# Pydantic list of models with the same name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

Let's say I want to have a User model which also contains "friends" field which has to be a list of users:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    friends: List[User]
```

but it's not possible. Is there a way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you need to use `update_forward_refs`, see [self-referencing models](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/postponed_annotations/) in the docs.

```py
from typing import List

from devtools import debug

from pydantic import BaseModel


class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    friends: List['User']


User.update_forward_refs()

u = User(id=123, name='hello', friends=[dict(id=321, name='goodbye', friends=[])])

debug(u)
```

outputs:

```py
test.py:18 <module>
    u: User(
        id=123,
        name='hello',
        friends=[
            User(
                id=321,
                name='goodbye',
                friends=[],
            ),
        ],
    ) (User)
```